# Is it worth betting on this case?

Tags: probability, statistics, puzzle, game-theory

Let's imagine a game which uses an unbiased coin.

Starting with $X$ dollars, your total increases $50\%$ every time you flip heads. But if the coin lands on tails, you lose $40\%$ of your total. You can play this game $N$ times. On each turn, you must bet the total amount you had on the last turn.

Is it worth betting on this case? How can we formalize this in order to have this answer in the general case?

Is it easier to formalize this for a specific value of $X$ and $N$? Let us assume, for example $X = 100$ dollars and $N = 100$ turns.

PS: This scenario appears in an article discussing some ideas of Ole Peters, a theoretical physicist who is claiming that Everything we know about modern economics is wrong.

Comment: I think the point is that if you repeat this bet over and over your wealth converges to zero almost surely even though the expectation value of the bet is positive (and in fact your expected wealth grows exponentially in the number of times you repeat). Whether this means “everything we know about modern economics is wrong”, I’m not sure, though it seems like if could be a sensible critique of the “maximize expected value” paradigm.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Interesting - your wealth converges to zero almost surely in the long term, but since expectation is positive and you can never actually go broke, you can also pick any target amount of winnings, and achieve that almost surely. If you keep playing forever, you'll definitely wind up virtually broke, but you can also definitely stop at some point and walk away with \$1M, or \$1B, or any amount you choose.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen If you play long enough, you are guaranteed to see any arbitrary sequence of wins and losses, including ones where wins outnumber losses by any arbitrary amount. This is basically the reverse of "gambler's ruin", which states that even playing a positive EV game will eventually lead to bankruptcy, since you are guaranteed at some point to see a streak of losses long enough to do so. Here, we have the opposite, since we *can't* go bankrupt, and are guaranteed to see a steak of wins long enough. A 1-D random walk visits *every* reachable value infinitely many times.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie No, that's not right. While it's true that a random walk visits every reachable value, your wealth when the walk hits some given value decreases as time goes on. So say you wait till you've won 100 more times then you lost, i.e. the walk hits 100. Then your wealth has been multiplied by $(3/2)^{N+100} (3/5)^N$ where $N=(T-100)/2$ where $T$ is the number of rounds it took to you to get there. So that's $(3/2)^{100} (9/10)^N,$ which will be less than 1 if $N$ is large enough.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Hmm, I think you're right, since an asymmetric random walk isn't guaranteed to visit every value. I originally though this random walk would cross the initial bankroll value infinitely many times, meaning you'd get infinite chances to see the winning streak you need. But due to the asymmetry, I don't think that's the case - I think the probability of getting back to the initial value after a loss is less than 1, so you'll only get a finite number of chances starting from the initial value.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Yeah, exactly, that’s a good way of putting it. The driving random walk (the coin flips) is symmetrical, but the induced random walk for the log wealth has a negative drift, and that means it goes to -infinity almost surely and the probability of eventual passage for any value above the starting point decays exponentially with how far above it is (how steeply depends on the drift of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n$ represents the amont of money you have after the $n^{\text{th}}$ game played. Then $$X_n=\bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^{Q_n}\bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^{n-Q_n}X$$ where $Q_n \sim \text{Binomial}\bigg(n,\frac{1}{2}\bigg)$ and $X$ represents the initial amount of money that you had. The event of being "worth betting" corresponds to the event that $X_N>X$. Notice $$X_N>X \iff Q_N>\frac{N\ln(5/3)}{\ln(5/2)}$$ If $N$ is large we can say $Z=\frac{Q_N-N/2}{\sqrt{N}/2}$ is approximately $N(0,1)$ so $$P(X_N>X)\approx P\Bigg(Z>\sqrt{N}\bigg[\frac{2\ln(5/3)}{\ln(5/2)}-1\bigg]\Bigg)\approx 0$$

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to follow this answer. Can you explain the steps and how it answer the question?